# Masking the specific data inside the json value

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have to mask the data corresponding to IP and name. But, the masking function is treating **'\\2'** as a text and applying the masking on it instead of referencing the actual value.

```
with a as (
select (' {"Category": "test","abc": {"IP": "2401:4900:52f0:304a:34cd:93e6:ea31:3cce"}, "xyz": {"name": "Sai"}}') as json
)
select 
  *,
  regexp_replace(json, r'("_nanoseconds": )([":0-9a-zA-Z ]+)', concat('\\1',TO_HEX(md5('\\2')))) as dummy_json
dummy_json
from a;
```

Comment: What is `_nanoseconds` in this case?  Do you mean `IP`?  What is your expected output?

Comment: Yes, I will be passing `IP` and `name` in place of `_nanoseconds`. @Mikhail has shared the query as well as the output, that was my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below example

```
create temp function mask_json(json string, key string) as (
  replace (json, 
    regexp_extract(json, r'"' || key || '": "[^""]+"'), 
    concat('"' || key || '": "' || to_hex(md5(regexp_extract(json, r'"' || key || '": "([^""]+)"'))) || '"')
  ));
with a as (
  select (' {"Category": "test","abc": {"IP": "2401:4900:52f0:304a:34cd:93e6:ea31:3cce"}, "xyz": {"name": "Sai"}}') as json
)
select 
  mask_json(mask_json(json, 'IP'), 'name') masked_json
from a;
```

with output

[image]